# How to declare multiple interface constraints in golang?

Tags: go

Suppose I have two interfaces:

```golang
interface A {...}
interface B {...}
```

Now I want to define a function to accept some param of interface A & B(i.e., param implements both interface A and B):

```golang
func test(param A & B) {...} // any similar syntax?
```

I don't want to write a new interface to embed other interfaces every time I want to refer to multiple interfaces like this:

```golang
interface C {
  A
  B
}
func test(param C) {...} //ok with 2 interfaces, what about 3, 4 or even 9?
```

I don't know how to express intersection type in golang, any ideas?

Comment: "I don't want to write a new interface to embed other interfaces" why not? That's a good way to do this in Go. Or you define a new interface C with all the methods from A and B (that you want to invoke ). Types in Go do not declare which interfaces they implement - a type implements an interface if it's methodset is a superset of the methods of the interface

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I don't want to write a new interface to embed other interfaces because of interface composability. What if I dynamically need various interface compositions? If I have 4 interface to compose, then I need 4! new interfaces just for function param constraint?

Comment: you need an interface for the methods that you want to invoke on something. Go isn't Java, interfaces aren't part of the type of something, they're just a way of saying what you want to be able to invoke on the thing passed to you. Not sure what "dynamically needed interfaces compositions are" but chances are, you're making things far too complex.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt When talking about types and interfaces, we need to define what types are about. "they're just a way of saying what you want to be able to invoke on the thing passed to you" this sentence can also be used on structs. Both types and interfaces are used to constraint some data's behavior. "dynamically needed interfaces compositions" means I have various interface composition orders in various packages of my project. In TypeScript this is called intersection type; In Haskell this is called multiple typeclass constraint;I think interface composition is useful under many circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in go as it is an obscure control flow that Go is designed to avoid.

Types aren't required to implement interfaces by name so my recommendation is to declare anonymous interfaces for each argument containing only the methods you know this function requires.